How to Automate Updating Source and Include Files in Xcode Project
I'm currently working on a cross-platform project involving both Android and iOS. Whenever there are changes to the core c++ code, I need to update the Xcode project accordingly.  The manual process I follow is:

Open Xcode.
Delete the existing source and include files.
Re-add the updated source and include files to the project.

This process is repetitive and time-consuming. I've looked into possible ways to automate it but haven't found a viable solution yet.
